# Three.JS TWEEN move object to other object speed

Tags: javascript, three.js, move, tween

I make a game where a object moves to other objectes.

```
new TWEEN.Tween( object.position ).to({
   x: Math.position = pointX,
   z: Math.position.z = pointZ
}).easing( TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None).start();
```

The problem is that the object moves with different speeds to each point, because the points have different positions.

How can I make the speed of my object to the points always the same?

Comment: You know distance, you have desired speed, so the time is distance / speed. Where and how do you set duration of tweens?

Comment: The duration is the second parameter of tween.to(object, duration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it will look like this:

```
var speed = 5; // units a second, the speed we want
var currentPoint = new THREE.Vector3();  // we will re-use it


// this part is in a function of event listener of, for example, a button
currentPoint.copy(cube.position); // cube is the object to move
var distance = currentPoint.distanceTo(destinationPoint.position)
var duration = (distance / speed) * 1000; // in milliseconds
new TWEEN.Tween(cube.position)
  .to(destinationPoint.position, duration) // destinationPoint is the object of destination
  .start();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/h2s2nnpc/) example. Have a look at the `tweening()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your help